# How to fix broken boot configuration

Tags: boot, refind

I had windows and manjaro installed as partitions of the same ssd. I installed refind with a theme from manjaro and used it for 5 years. Then for some mistake i made (i'm not clear what it was tbh) my manjaro partition broke and i deleted it. I resized my windows partition (which needed more space) and then reinstalled again manjaro on the remaining space.
When i start my pc, however, refind is still present (don't know how this works) and the manjaro boot option is refered to the old broken manjaro. If i boot it, it goes into a grub rescue terminal where i can't seem to do anything. I have found no way to boot the new manjaro and can only boot windows from refind.

If i boot my bios, the same exact options are shown: refind, windows, manjaro (old not-working version fallbacking into grub rescue).

What can i do?